# Whats going on here? Changing values in arrays to blank space

Tags: c, arrays

I am self-learning C online and I wrote a test program to change the values within individual arrays thus:

```
char name [20] = "Michael Blameson";

printf("My name is %s\n", name);
name[0]='P';
name[1]='e';
name[2]='t';
name[3]='e';
name[4]='r';
name[5]="";
name[6]= "";
printf("My name is %s\n", name););
```

I am trying to leave the last two spaces blank,  so it reads “My name is Peter Blameson”. However, when I run it, it reads “My name is Peter?? Blameson”

What’s going on here?

Comment: You are trying to assign string literal to a variable of type `char`.

Comment: Did the compiler say anything like "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"?

Comment: I don't even understand what that means.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `''` isn't valid C

Comment: @ikegami Gah! I meant with a space inside. Been doing too much shell programming lately...

Comment: So `' '` (there is a space in the middle), not `""`.

Comment: @ZenMournster: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score?

Answer (score 4):

`""` is a string literal, which is unmodifiable array of `char`. It will be converted to a pointer pointing at its first element and since `name[5]` and `name[6]` are `char`, the pointer will be converted to an integer in implementation-defined manner.

You cannot delete characters (elements) in `name` without shifting characters after the characters to be deleted. To change the characters to space, you can use space character `' '`. To shift elements, you can use `memmove()` (you cannot use `memcpy()` nor `strcpy()` because they won't work when the source and destination are overwrapped).

```
memmove(&name[5], &name[7], strlen(&name[7]) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove characters that way, they need to be replaced with other characters:

```
name[5] = ' ';
name[6] = ' ';
```

Of course you will end up printing:

```
My name is Peter   Blameson
```

Which is not ideal. Instead you have to move the remaining characters (using [`memmove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memmove.html)) up to fill in the space:

```
memmove(&name[5], &name[7], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes

```
name[5]= ' ';
name[6]= ' ';
```

Otherwise you need to move " Blameson" two positions left using standard C function `memmove`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char name [20] = "Michael Blameson";

    printf( "My name is %s\n", name );

    name[0] = 'P';
    name[1] = 'e';
    name[2] = 't';
    name[3] = 'e';
    name[4] = 'r';

    memmove( name + 5, name + 7, strlen( name + 7 ) + 1 );

    printf( "My name is %s\n", name );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
My name is Michael Blameson
My name is Peter Blameson
```

Or if you do not want to use magic numbers then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char name [20] = "Michael Blameson";

    printf( "My name is %s\n", name );

    size_t i = 0;

    name[i++] = 'P';
    name[i++] = 'e';
    name[i++] = 't';
    name[i++] = 'e';
    name[i++] = 'r';

    size_t j = strchr( name, ' ' ) - name;

    memmove( name + i, name + j, strlen( name + j ) + 1 );

    printf( "My name is %s\n", name );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is the same as shown above.

```
My name is Michael Blameson
My name is Peter Blameson
```

As for statements

```
name[5]="";
name[6]= "";
```

in your program then `""` is a string literal (instead of character literal) that has type of array `char [1]` that initialized like `{ '\0' }` and which in the expressions in the assignment statements is converted to pointer to its first and single element. The program should issue a message for these statements.

Comment: Then I get error "empty character constant', expected expression.

Comment: You need to use `'<hit the spacebar here>'`, not `''`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are using double quotes for your spaces (" ").
In C, all characters for your char[] are indicated by single quotes ('') or integer ASCII values. In this case, your character is a space - ' ', and your ASCII integer is 32.

Your "" is referring to a C string literal which is a constant global pointer created at runtime.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/2000px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `name[5]="";` attempts to store the pointer to the beginning of an empty string into a `char` array element. Double quotes represent string literals in C, which are basically pointers to the first element of the `char` array holding the string.

If you want to assign a space, use single quotes instead of double. Single quotes denote a character value. (Single quoted values can actually be used as a one-byte integer, but that is not advisable).

```
name[5] = ' ';
name[6] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Space characters are not represented as `""`, which is an empty string literal, but as `' '` (space blank space). You might have misread your book.

The modified code would be:

```
char name[20] = "Michael Blameson";

printf("My name is %s\n", name);
name[0] = 'P';
name[1] = 'e';
name[2] = 't';
name[3] = 'e';
name[4] = 'r';
name[5] = ' ';
name[6] = ' ';
printf("My name is %s\n", name);
```

Running that produces output: `My name is Peter   Blameson`.

To remove the 2 extra spaces between `Peter` and `Blameson`, you can use a `for` loop or a string library function:

```
for (int i = 6; i < 18; i++) {
    name[i] = name[i + 2];
}
```

Or

```
memmove(name + 6, name + 8, 12);
```

Both of these methods will copy the contents of the array 2 positions to the left.  You cannot use `strcpy(name + 6, name + 8)` because `strcpy()` invokes undefined behavior if the source and destination arrays overlap.